# Multiplication - Matrix by imaginary unit

Tags: eigen

I would like to ask if anybody knows why this is not working:

For example, let

```
SparseMatrix<int> A
```

and

```
SparseMatrix<std::complex<float> > B
```

I would like to do the following math:

B=i*A

As code:

```
std::complex<float> c;
c=1.0i;
B=A.cast<std::complex<float> >()*c;
```

or equivalent:

```
B=A.cast<std::complex<float> >()*1.0i;
```

I expect all real values of A to be imaginary in B but
there are only zeros as (0,0).

Example:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace Eigen;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int rows=5, cols=5;

    SparseMatrix<int> A(rows,cols);
    A.setIdentity();


    SparseMatrix<std::complex<float> > B;
    std::complex<float> c;
    c=1i;

    B=A.cast<std::complex<float> >()*1.0i;
    //B=A.cast<std::complex<float> >()*c;

    cout << B << endl;

    return 0;    
}
```

compile with:
g++ [name].cpp -o [name]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Does it help if you use I instead of i? I read in the c standard (and perhaps in this context it is different) that I not i repesents the imaginary unit. Or else should you not <#include complex> which will define lower case i?

Comment: Above should say #include <complex>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Unfortunately i get the same results.

Comment: As a workaround i use now
    c=std::complex<float>(0,1);
which works (c*c=(-1,0)).

Comment: I am glad that worked. It does sound like it was not recognizing the expression 1.0i.

Comment: It doesn't ! But the problem has been solved by ggael in the following post!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable c++14 to get `1.0i` working as expected. With GCC or clang, you need to add the `-std=c++14` compiler option.

Then, you can simply do:

```
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(3,3);
MatrixXcd B;
B = A * 1.0i;
```

Same with a `SparseMatrix`.

Comment: Great!
Thanks a lot!